# How to write a `.circleci/config.yml` file

Tags: python, django, docker, circleci

I am going through a tutorial. In that tutorial I learn how to CI in Travis-CI. But as I am learner I am not able to find a way to write the same configure file in CircleCI.

How can I convert my `.travis.yml` to `.circleci/config.yml`?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser -D user

USER user
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"

services: 

    app:

        build:

            context: .

        ports: 

            - "8000-8000"

        volumes: 

            - ./app:/app

        command: >

            sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

**.travis.yml**

```
language: python

python:
  - "3.8"

services:
  - docker

before_script: pip install docker-compose

script:
  - docker-compose run app sh -c "python manage.py test && flake8"
```

Comment: Please take a moment to learn the formatting tools here, especially before posting your next question. The formatting system here is called Markdown, and learning the basics - such as code formatting - will be infinitely valuable to you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this should do the trick:

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/python:3.8
    steps:
      - run:
          name: "Build my app"
          command: |
            pip install docker-compose
            docker-compose run app sh -c "python manage.py test && flake8"

workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - build
```